# C# function that generates timeline items when threshold is crossed

Tags: c#, .net, for-loop, casting

I'm really stumped on how to achieve this. I have a list of reservations with overlapping start and or end times, from which I have to generate timelime items. These timeline items should only be generated in 3 styles: OK, Warning or Error.

Default start of day is 08:00 and end of the day is 18:00.

- OkCount is 1
- WarningCount is 2
- ErrorCount is 3

Everytime a threshold is crossed a new timeline item should be added. The result from the following reservations:

- reservation from 9:00 till 12:00
- reservation from 10:00 till 12:00
- reservation from 11:00 till 12:00
- reservation from 13:00 till 14:00

Should give these timeline items as a result:

- timeline item from 8:00 till 10:00 with OK
- timeline item from 10:00 till 11:00 with Warning (almost full capacity)
- timeline item from 11:00 till 12:00 with Error (full)
- timeline itsm from 12:00 till 18:00 with OK (between 0 and 1 reservations in this time)

I've already tried a few things with for and foreach loops but I really am stumped. Currently, with the code below, I'm having the issue that incorrect timeline items are being generated. This is most likely due to the way I loop through the code. I would like to check the occupancy at any given minute throughout the day and if it crosses one of 3 thresholds create a new timeline item accordingly, without having to loop through every single minute.

The occupancy when looped through currently does not increase or decrease except for the last iteration of the loop. It might be a lot easier to just loop through all minutes of the day and check the occupancy that way but it seems really inefficient.

### Convert function that is WIP

```cs
var startTime = TimeSpan.FromHours(8);
var endTime = TimeSpan.FromHours(20);
var occupancy = 0;
var lastTime = startTime;
var timeLineItems = new List<TimeLineItem>();
var lastThresholdHit = 0;
var totalTime = (endTime - startTime).TotalMinutes;

for (var i = 0; i < totalTime; i++)
{
    var currentTime = startTime + TimeSpan.FromMinutes(i);
    var newOccupancy = processedReservations.Count(r => r.StartTime <= currentTime && r.EndTime >= currentTime);
    if (occupancy != newOccupancy)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(currentTime + ": " + newOccupancy);
        if (newOccupancy <= _timeLineOkCount && lastThresholdHit != _timeLineOkCount)
        {
            var itemText = lastTime.ToString(@"hh\:mm") + " - " + currentTime.ToString(@"hh\:mm");
            var item = new TimeLineItem(Color.Success, itemText);
            timeLineItems.Add(item);
            lastThresholdHit = _timeLineOkCount;
            lastTime = currentTime;
        } else
        if (newOccupancy < _timeLineErrorCount && lastThresholdHit != _timeLineWarningCount)
        {
            var itemText = lastTime.ToString(@"hh\:mm") + " - " + currentTime.ToString(@"hh\:mm");
            var item = new TimeLineItem(Color.Warning, itemText);
            timeLineItems.Add(item);
            lastThresholdHit = _timeLineWarningCount;
            lastTime = currentTime;
        }
        else
        if (lastThresholdHit != _timeLineErrorCount)
        {
            var itemText = lastTime.ToString(@"hh\:mm") + " - " + currentTime.ToString(@"hh\:mm");
            var item = new TimeLineItem(Color.Error, itemText);
            timeLineItems.Add(item);
            lastThresholdHit = _timeLineErrorCount;
            lastTime = currentTime;
        }
    }
    occupancy = newOccupancy;
}
if (lastTime < endTime)
{
    var itemText = lastTime.ToString(@"hh\:mm") + " - " + endTime.ToString(@"hh\:mm");
    var item = new TimeLineItem(Color.Success, itemText);
    timeLineItems.Add(item);
}

var orderedTimeLineItems = timeLineItems.OrderBy(i => i.ItemTimeText).ToList();
return orderedTimeLineItems;
```

I still have some weirdness with the code above. In some cases the debug log returns an occupancy of 0 where it should not and the items generated do not yet show the correct times.

### TimeLineItem class

```cs
public class TimeLineItem
    {
        public Color ItemColor { get; set; }
        public string ItemTimeText { get; set; }

        public TimeLineItem(Color itemColor, string itemTimeText)
        {
            ItemColor = itemColor;
            ItemTimeText = itemTimeText;
        }
    }
```

### Enum class Color

```cs
public enum Color 
{
    Success,
    Warning,
    Error
}
```

### Reservation class

```cs
public class Reservation 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public TimeSpan StartTime { get; set; } 
    public TimeSpan EndTime { get; set; }   
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }

    public Reservation(int id, TimeSpan startTime, TimeSpan endTime, DateTime date)
    {
        Id = id;
        StartTime = startTime;
        EndTime = endTime;
        Date = date;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please could you edit your code so that it doesn't have a blank line for every other line? I suspect that's not what the code looks like in your editor. Next, it would be really helpful if you could provide a [mcve] - not just "here's some code" but "here's code that you can copy/paste/compile/run with sample data" along with expected output and actual output.

Comment: Will do, 1 moment.

Comment: `i <= startTimes.Count` and then `if (lastTime < startTimes[i])` - that's going to fail for a start, as `list[list.Count]` is never valid.

Comment: Sorry, that really doesn't help me to understand what you're asking. If you think your current code is working, what are you asking for? (I would at least expect an exception on the last iteration.) If your current code *isn't* working, please give more details about that. Read https://jonskeet.uk/links/stack-hints for more details.

Comment: My mistake, apparently in my latest code I already correct the `i <= startTimes.Count` to `i < startTimes.Count`. Also, that is a very nice post I'll give it a thorough read.

Comment: I've now updated the code block to the latest version and made some amendments. @JonSkeet

Comment: You still haven't clarified what I asked at 09:01:00Z though.

Comment: My bad, currently I'm having the issue that incorrect timeline items are being generated. This is most likely due to the way I loop through the code. I would like to check the occupancy at any given minute throughout the day and if it crosses one of 3 thresholds create a new timeline item accordingly. The occupancy when looped through currently does not increase or decrease except for the last iteration of the loop.


It might be a lot easier to just loop through all minutes of the day and check the occupancy that way but it seems really inefficient.

Comment: All of that should be in the question, with a sample app we can run, including expected output and actual output.

Comment: What are the conditions for `Ok`, `Warning` and `Error`? Also, rather than Edit1, 2, 3 just make your question full and complete. ie/ expected input --> expected output

Comment: FYI - Calling the status (`Sucess`, `Warning`, `Error`) a color is probably is bad design decision.  A color is supposed to designate exactly that, color, and likely it will conflict with `System.Drawing.Color` at the UI level.

Comment: It is an imported Enum type from Mudblazor that I'm using. Just a placeholder essentially.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Function improvement and fully working

Instead of using minute granularity and looping through every single minute I decided to take a different more efficient approach by using .Aggregate() and a few other LINQ methods. The final result works really well except for the start item time being 00:00 for some reason. I worked my way around that issue by checking if the item start time is before the allowed start time and if it is then set it to the start time.

The codeblocks below combined give the final result working function.

### Main function

```cs
public async Task<List<TimeLineItem>> GetTimeLineItems()
{
    var reservations = await _reservationCollection.GetReservations();
    if (reservations.Count < 1)
    {
        return new List<TimeLineItem>();
    }

    var processedReservations = reservations.Where(r => r.Date.Date == DateTime.Today)
        .OrderBy(r => r.StartTime).ToArray();
    var mergedReservations = new List<Reservation>();
    if (processedReservations.Length < 1) return new List<TimeLineItem>();
    var currentReservation = processedReservations[0];
    for (var i = 1; i < processedReservations.Length; i++)
    {
        var nextReservation = processedReservations[i];
        if ((nextReservation.StartTime - currentReservation.EndTime).TotalMinutes <= _timeMarginInMinutes * 2 &&
            currentReservation.Charger == nextReservation.Charger)
        {
            currentReservation.EndTime = nextReservation.EndTime;
        }
        else
        {
            mergedReservations.Add(currentReservation);
            currentReservation = nextReservation;
        }
    }

    var reservationEvents = processedReservations
        .SelectMany(r => new List<ReservationEvent>
            { new(r.StartTime, -1), new(r.EndTime, 1) })
        .OrderBy(r => r.Moment).ToArray();
    var chargers = await _chargerCollection.GetChargers();
    var chargerAmount = chargers.Count;
    var result = reservationEvents
        .Prepend(new ReservationEvent(_startTime,  chargerAmount)) // Add initial state
        .GroupBy(r => r.Moment)
        .Select(group => new
        {
            Moment = group.Key,
            Action = group.Sum(r => r.Action)
        })
        .Where(r => r.Action != 0)
        .OrderBy(r => r.Moment)
        .Aggregate(
            new DayAccumulator
            {
                Availability = 0, // Will be set to 3 by first ReservationEvent
                States = new List<TimelineState> { new() { Color = Color.Success }}
            },
            (acc, r) =>
            {
                acc.Availability += r.Action;

                var lastState = acc.States.Last();
                if (lastState.Color != GetAvailabilityColor(acc.Availability))
                {
                    acc.States.Add(new TimelineState
                    {
                        Moment = r.Moment,
                        Color = GetAvailabilityColor(acc.Availability)
                    });
                }
                return acc;
            }).States;
    var lastItem = result.Last();
    var timeLineItems = new List<TimeLineItem>();
    for (var i = 0; i < result.Count - 1; i++)
    {
        if (result[i].Moment < _startTime) result[i].Moment = _startTime;
        timeLineItems.Add(new TimeLineItem(result[i].Color, $"{result[i].Moment:hh\\:mm} - {result[i + 1].Moment:hh\\:mm}"));
    }

    if (lastItem.Moment < _endTime)
    {
        timeLineItems.Add(new TimeLineItem(lastItem.Color, $"{lastItem.Moment:hh\\:mm} - {_endTime:hh\\:mm}"));
    }
    return timeLineItems;
}
```

### Helper function to get correct color from availability

```cs
private Color GetAvailabilityColor(int availability)
{
    if (availability >= _okAvailabilityAmount)
    {
        return Color.Success;
    }
    if (availability >= _warningAvailabilityAmount)
    {
        return Color.Warning;
    }
    return Color.Error;
}
```

### Helper classes and records

```cs
internal class DayAccumulator
{
    public int Availability { get; set; }
    public List<TimelineState> States { get; init; } = new();
}

internal class TimelineState
{
    public TimeSpan Moment { get; set; }
    public Color Color { get; set; }
}

internal record ReservationEvent(TimeSpan Moment, int Action);
```

All of this code combined does exactly what I want it to do.

Answer (score 4):

Whenever I try to attack a problem like this, I find it really useful to visualize the problem. Something like this:

[image]

As you can see, we know that a new block can only start at the start time or end time of a reservation. So the code can simply loop through all times, at whatever granularity you require, looking for start or end times of reservations and calculating as appropriate.

The code  can be written something like (assuming minute granularity):

```
var startTimes = reservations.GroupBy(x => x.StartTime).ToDictionary(k => k.Key, v => v.Count());
var endTimes = reservations.GroupBy(x => x.EndTime).ToDictionary(k => k.Key, v => v.Count());
    
var dayStart = TimeSpan.FromHours(8);
var dayEnd = TimeSpan.FromHours(18);
    
var currentCount = 0;
var result = new List<TimeLineItem>();
var currentStart = dayStart;
var currentEnd = dayEnd;
for(var time = dayStart; time <= dayEnd;time = time.Add(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1)))
{           
    if(startTimes.TryGetValue(time, out var numStart))
    {               
        if(currentCount>0)
        {   
            result.Add(CreateItem(currentStart, time, currentCount));
            currentStart = time;                
        }   
        currentCount += numStart;   
    }
    if(endTimes.TryGetValue(time, out var numEnd))
    {
        if(currentCount>1)
        {   
            result.Add(CreateItem(currentStart, time, currentCount));
            currentStart = time;
        }
        currentCount -= numEnd;
    }
}   
result.Add(CreateItem(currentStart, dayEnd, currentCount));
```

This produces the exact output you expect :

```
08:00:00 - 10:00:00 (Success)
10:00:00 - 11:00:00 (Warning)
11:00:00 - 12:00:00 (Error)
12:00:00 - 18:00:00 (Success)
```

Live example: https://dotnetfiddle.net/WLomdH

There are surely some edge cases not covered, but this should give you a good base to test from.

Comment: This is indeed a very nice intermediate solution. Would it be better to loop through the list of reservation, create an object for each start and end time with a type definition and add it all to a single list and then loop through that list? If so, I do somewhat have an idea on how to do that, but would need some help realising the final steps.

Comment: @OwendB But you cant do that, you need to calculate the count at any given moment (minute). So just looping each reservation is not enough

Comment: In any case, I was just answering the question as asked. I think there is far more to this than your question lets on. Hence my last sentence.

Comment: Yes indeed it is very interesting. Might need to make a part 2 to this.